# Which ssh public key and private key is my user using?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

For what I understand there's needs to be an exchange of keys pairs so an ssh connection takes place. I am practicing remote port forwarding. I am in metasploitable 3 and want to expose the service running in port 631 to port 80 in my kali. It works! I'm logged as leia_organa in my server and entered this command ssh -v -T -R
80:localhost:631 vagrant@172.28.128.10 I get this output (see picture):

[image: 1]

You can see that the system is trying to use private key /home/leia_organa/.ssh/id_rsa. The problem is that there is no such file. Leia_organa doesn't have a id_rsa nor an id_rsa.pub

[image: 2]

So my question is: which public and private keys is leia_organa using so the connection is succefull?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is difficult to understand.

From all I can see your post is NOT using any public/private keys to authenticate, hence why its dropping back to password authentication.

To see what public keys can (or at least may be able to) connect, you need to look at the keys listed in authorized_keys. Typically, each line contains 1 ssh public key with 3 fields separated by space.  The last one is a description field and normally gives an indication of the associated key.

(The known_hosts file is not used for authorization - rather its used by the client to remember systems its connected to - if the ssh server identification has changed it uses this to pop up an error, similarly, if there has not been a prior connection to the server it asks for confirmation)

If you want to make a new connection to a server, generate an SSH key pair on the client (eg using ssh-key-gen under Linux).  Then add the contents of the "xxxxx.pub" file to the authorized_keys file, and use the corresponding ssh key to log in.

Comment: So the ssh protocol doesn't require the exchange of keys? Is it just an option?

Comment: Technically speaking ssh does rrquire exchange of keys from the server to the client - to this is "automatically in the background" and the key in questiin is the host ssh daemon key associated with known_hosts. to enable encryption.  A user does not require a key to log in to a seever unless the server is configured to enforce key based login - commonly users can log in with the password associated with their account (ie the passeord hashed in /etc/shadow for their user on the server). This is configureable though.